# Proving inequality given some conditions

Tags: inequality

I want to show that $-x^2y^2-y^4+4y^2 \geq 0$, if $x^4+2y^2 \leq 4$ and $-x^2y^2-y^4+4y^2 \leq 0$, if $x^4+2y^2 \geq 32$. Is there a factoring trick that helps to prove this explicitly?

Comment: What if $x = 0.29$, $y = -0.05$? Then $x^4 + 2y^2 \leq 4$, but $xy - x^3y - x^2 y^2 - y^4 + 4 y^2 \ngeq 0$.

Comment: The second one is true with the additional condition $x, y\ge 0$. The first one is true if $x, y\ge 0$ and $x^4 + 2y^2 \le 1$.

Comment: The second inequality is wrong if $x=y=0.$

Comment: @BodyDouble Thank you all for your comments. I corrected the inequality.

Comment: @RiverLi Thank you all for your comments. I corrected the inequality.

Comment: @nguyenhuyen_ag Thank you all for your comments. I corrected the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

1. For the first question you need to prove
   $$
   -2x^2-2y^2+8 \geq 0
   $$
   with the condition $-2y^2 \geq x^4 -4$. This condition implies $x^2 < 2$ since otherwise it can never be fulfilled. Combining the two gives the sharper $
   -2x^2+x^4+4 \geq 0
   $ or $(x^2-1)^2 +3\ge 0$, done.
2. For the second question you need to prove
   $$
   -2x^2-2y^2+8 \leq 0
   $$
   with the condition $-2y^2 \leq x^4 -32$. This condition needs to be applied only for $x^2 < \sqrt{32}$ since otherwise it is fulfilled anyway. So for this case, we have  $
   -2x^2+x^4-24 \leq 0
   $ or $(x^2-1)^2 \le 25$, or $x^2 \le 6$, but this is fulfilled with  $x^2 < \sqrt{32} < 6$.
   Consider the other case  $x^2 \ge \sqrt{32}$, then we see directly that $
   -2x^2-2y^2+8 \leq -2x^2 +8 \leq - 2 \sqrt{32} +8 < 0
   $